# Java subtraction of floats is infinity?

Tags: java, floating-point, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

In my debugger I can see the following values:

```
float min = -3.1931721E38
float max = 3.3434891E38

float temp = (max-min);
```

This results in infinity. Why is that? (2-2^23)·2^127 is larger than the temp variable right?

Comment: No one answered your actual question, “(2-2^23)·2^127 is larger than the temp variable right?”. The answer is no (and you meant 2^-23).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The mathematical result for this subtraction is larger than the largest possible `Float` value, [`Float.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Float.MAX_VALUE).  Java follows the IEEE rules for floating-point arithmetic, which result in `Infinity`.

If you want the result, then you can use `double`s instead, which have greater precision and a far greater range of valid values.

Answer (score 7):

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.1)

> The result of a floating-point multiplication is determined by the rules of IEEE 754 arithmetic:
>
> - [...]
> - If the magnitude of the product is too large to represent, we say the operation **overflows**; **the result is then an infinity of appropriate sign**.

Answer (score 0):

A `Float` value is only 32 bits ( or 4 bytes). So the container you are using is too small for a computable answer. The buffer then overflows.

Try using a larger data structure like a `double` which is a container of 64 bits ( or 8 bytes)